# Question that is VERY similar but has a very different answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

*The question on SO which prompted me to come ask: [What would be the most rational way to parse youtube video link for video ID in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717098/what-would-be-the-most-rational-way-to-parse-youtube-video-link-for-video-id-in-p/)*

In this case, the user has posted a question that seems to be an exact duplicate.  However, the user posts a small code snippet and asks how to get a particular part.  The duplicate question linked to deals with any YouTube URL, and as such has a very complex regex answer to accompany it.  However, this question is on a specific URL.  At this point, it is unclear whether the poster cares about the additional YouTube formats.  My answer has a very precise code snippet using built-in PHP functions for parsing various parts of a URL.  Thus, the answer is very different.  It seems to me this is not an exact duplicate as per my understanding of [When is a duplicate question not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/when-is-a-duplicate-question-not-a-duplicate) and [What is an exact duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38375/what-is-an-exact-duplicate).

Obviously, I'd like to see the duplicate question status removed on this particular question as I have the answer, but what should I do about it and other similar situations?  Build the rest of my reputation up to 3000 and vote to reopen?

**Edit:** It also seems to me the fact it got 8 upvotes before being closed as a duplicate credibility to the fact that it isn't a duplicate.  In my experience, answers to duplicate questions don't get many upvotes that quickly.

Comment: As a side note, it's difficult to wade through all the questions here on meta about duplicate questions.  The wording is all so similar, but each question seems to have a different aspect of the same rough idea!

Comment: I think it's a gray area here. Fact is that your answer would help the old question better(Youtube API - Extract video ID). But if you got 9 upvotes and the question is still available for all to see, I think you still won here.