# Flagging - Exact duplicate flag declined - Why?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253216/) as an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748), which I believe is completely legitimate, as the text for the exact duplicate flag is:

> This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on
>   this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question.

The asked question is the exact same problem as the earlier question. Even my answer on the duplicate question, which was slightly modified from the original question's answer, was marked as accepted, clearly showing that both questions are extremely similar.

Even [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38375/what-is-an-exact-duplicate) on meta states that questions are closed as duplicates if it is found that "an earlier question to which nothing substantial is added by the new question."

Since I can't cast close votes, I flagged the question as a duplicate. Am I misunderstanding the duplicate question flag? Does it literally mean "exact, word-for-word, verbatim question as an earlier one"? I don't think that's the case, judging by the text for the exact duplicate flag, which makes me believe that my flag is legitimate and was improperly declined.

Finally, declining a flag that has a valid substance behind it is counterintuitive, as it discourages future flags, inherently begrudging somebody who is trying to help the site. Even if the person who reviewed my submission thought it was improperly flagged, a "disputed" resolution seems more appropriate then "declined", especially since "declined" states that there was "no evidence to support it", which is clearly not the case.

Comment: Odd - your flag looks legit to me

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about this.  At your current flag weight of 280, a single accepted flag will cancel out the declined one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Sounds good. I wanted to be sure that I was using the system properly to avoid adding unnecessary work / clutter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Finally, declining a flag that has a valid substance behind it is counterintuitive, as it discourages future flags, inherently begrudging somebody who is trying to help the site. Even if the person who reviewed my submission thought it was improperly flagged, a "disputed" resolution seems more appropriate then "declined", especially since "declined" states that there was "no evidence to support it", which is clearly not the case.

That's not how it works. Moderators don't have the option to "dispute" flags unless we go through the 10k flag queue, but that still doesn't dismiss the flag. Dismissing a flag can only be done as "helpful" or "declined".

While I agree that it can be demoralizing to have a flag declined, please understand that flags are declined because a moderator thinks they aren't valid. Nobody looks at a flag they think is valid and decides to decline it anyway. We appreciate all flags we receive even if some of them end up declined.

Comment: One of my first flags (which was an incorrect flag in hindsight) was marked as: `not a real question – Nov 8 at 7:34   disputed`, which from what I can tell does not affect your flag weight. Just curious, how did that resolution occur if not by moderator action?

Comment: @nickb Users with 10000+ reputation have access to a flag queue and see flags that correspond to close votes there. They can't dismiss a flag, but they can disagree with it. When the flag is eventually dismissed (by a moderator or automatically if the question is closed, for example), the flag will be recorded as "disputed".

Comment: I see now. Thanks for clearing things up - I was under the impression that "disputed" was a valid resolution, and thought that it was more appropriate for my flag. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @nickb: Also note that, because a mod's vote is binding, they can't actually *dispute* a flag in the moderator queue.  They can only *accept* or *decline*.

Answer (score 4):

That was an oversight on my part.  Reviewing it further, it's an exact dupe (the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag did indeed throw me off) , and has now been closed as such.